# Check if value is found in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to check if a certain number is contained within an array.

I have tried using `if (value in mines)` and `var value = this.value; var isMine = mines.indexOf(value);`

But neither of these are working as expected. Can anyone explain why?
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dr1o9s53/1/)

### JS

```
    var mines = []
while (mines.length < 9){
  var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30)
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<mines.length;i++){
    if(mines[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
  }
  if(!found)mines[mines.length]=randomnumber;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blank").click(function() {
        var value = this.value;
        if (value in mines) { 
            $(this).removeClass("blank");
            $(this).addClass("bomb"); 
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("blank");
            $(this).addClass("safe");
        }
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="background">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="10"><div class="title">title here</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="10"><div class="info">text here</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="blank" value="1"></button></td>
        <td><button class="blank" value="2"></button></td>
        <td><button class="blank" value="3"></button></td>
    </tr>
<table>
</div>
```

Comment: change to `if( mines.indexOf(value) > -1 )`

Comment: Why not you use inArray  ? check this : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's an array you should be using `indexOf`, but you have two major issues.

Firstly the type has to match. The array has numbers, but the value of an element is always a string.
The easy solution is to parse the value as an integer

```
var value = parseInt( this.value, 10 );
```

Secondly, `indexOf` returns the index, and it will return `0` for the first item in the array, and `0` is falsy, so you have to actually check for `-1`, which is what `indexOf` returns if there is no match

```
if (mines.indexOf(value) != -1) {  ...
```

[**FIDDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dr1o9s53/4/)

A little simplified you'd end up with

```
var mines = [];
while (mines.length < 9){
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30);
    if ( mines.indexOf(randomnumber) == -1 ) 
        mines.push(randomnumber);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blank").click(function() {
        var isBomb = mines.indexOf( parseInt( this.value, 10 )) != -1;
        $(this).removeClass('blank').addClass(isBomb ? 'bomb' : 'safe');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dr1o9s53/9/)

Answer (score 1):

var value = +this.value

convert string to integer

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
var myArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var myString = myArray.join("***") + "***";
var mySubstring = "four";
var inArray = myString.indexOf(mySubstring + "***");

if(inArray >= 0){alert("It's in array");}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.value` returns a string. Try this. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr1o9s53/5/)

```
if (mines.indexOf(parseInt(value))!=-1) {  //or  if (parseInt(value) in mines) {
   $(this).removeClass("blank");
   $(this).addClass("bomb"); 
} else {           
   $(this).removeClass("blank");
   $(this).addClass("safe");
}
```